# Golang compiled regex to remove " and anything after and including @ in strings

Tags: regex, go

If I have a string that looks like `"Abraham Lincoln" @en`. What i want to do is if it contains @en then remove the quotes, but keep what is inside and remove @en.

What is the best way to do this in golang?

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: @AvinashRaj In that case `Abraham Lincoln`

Comment: @AvinashRaj I just finished a version of the regex explainer as a chrome extension.

Comment: Not as of yet. I'll have to implement that next. If you use chrome, look at my profile the link and screenshot is in it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One way you could do this based off your example input.

```
package main

import (
   "fmt"
   "regexp"
)

func main() {
   s := `"Abraham Lincoln" @en`
   reg := regexp.MustCompile(`"([^"]*)" *@en`)
   res := reg.ReplaceAllString(s, "${1}")
   fmt.Println(res) // Abraham Lincoln
}
```

If you have more data that follows the quotes, you could always change the expression to:

```
reg := regexp.MustCompile(`"([^"]*)".*@en`)
```

<kbd>[**GoPlay**](http://play.golang.org/p/hD2l4FiEan)</kbd>